# PMD+Maven+JAVA Error:: Can't find resource rulesets/comments.xml. Make sure the resource is a valid file or URL or is on the CLASSPATH

Tags: java, maven, pmd

while adding a custom ruleset of PMD , maven is producing an error -`net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetNotFoundException: Can't find resource rulesets/comments.xml.Make sure the resource is a valid file or URL or is on the CLASSPATH`.

For others rule sets like basic,naming etc its not giving any error.but when i add new ruleset it produced the error.
I also tried `<rule ref="rulesets/java/comments.xml/CommentRequired"/>`but it also giving the same error.
comments.xml is already available in pmd-5.0.2.jar file.

My POM.xml

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>pmd</groupId>
        <artifactId>pmd</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/site/
                        </outputDirectory>
                        <reportOutputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/site/
                        </reportOutputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>

            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <targetjdk>1.6</targetjdk>
                <skip>fasle</skip>
                <failOnViolation>false</failOnViolation>
                <failurePriority>4</failurePriority>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <rulesets>
                    <ruleset>src/main/resources/rulesets/MyRuleSet.xml</ruleset>
                </rulesets>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>check</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>cpd-check</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>cpd-check</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

My Custom Ruleset file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset>

<rule ref="rulesets/logging-java.xml/SystemPrintln">
    <priority>3</priority>
</rule>
<rule ref="rulesets/naming.xml/VariableNamingConventions">
    <priority>3</priority>
</rule>
<rule ref="rulesets/design.xml/UseSingleton">
    <priority>3</priority>
</rule>
<rule ref="rulesets/controversial.xml/UseConcurrentHashMap">
    <priority>3</priority>
</rule>
<rule ref="rulesets/basic.xml/OverrideBothEqualsAndHashcode">
    <priority>3</priority>
</rule>

<rule ref="rulesets/comments.xml/CommentRequired">
    <priority>3</priority>
</rule>
</ruleset>
```

Here is my maven stacktrace

```
    INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetNotFoundException: Can't find resource rulesets/comments.xml. Make sure the resource is a valid file or URL or is on the CLASSPATH
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.util.ResourceLoader.loadResourceAsStream(ResourceLoader.java:28)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:365)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:255)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:209)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:157)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.pmd.PmdReport.generateReport(PmdReport.java:222)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.pmd.PmdReport.execute(PmdReport.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.pmd.PmdReport.executeReport(PmdReport.java:149)
    at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport.generate(AbstractMavenReport.java:190)
    at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport.execute(AbstractMavenReport.java:99)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.executeForkedExecutions(MojoExecutor.java:364)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:198)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:318)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:414)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:357)
```

Answer (score 3):

The plugin only understands absolute paths. Try an absolute path and it should work. See the [documentation.](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/examples/usingRuleSets.html)

In order to make it independent from the local file system layout, use `${basedir}` to refer to your local path.

Comment: comments.xml is available in same place where others rule sets are i.e in rulesets.java package of pmd-5.0.2.jar. This jar file is already available in class path. Others rule sets are working except empty.xml comment.xml and string.xml.

Comment: According to the documentation, the path to your local file is not correct. It should rather be an absolute path. Try removing the comments.xml declaration from your custom file. Are there no errors, then?

Comment: Ok. Can't really explain that. If I was in your place I'd try to do it as suggested in the docs, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

it has to be "rulesets/java/comments.xml" instead of "rulesets/comments.xml".

my suspicion is, you picked up "rulesets/comments.xml" from some part of documentation which is out-dated, or was simply not tested before it was published.